# UIActivityIndicatorView Not disappearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uiactivityindicatorview

This seems to be a very simplistic issue, but I literally cannot get it working.

I have a section of my app which takes my user to a WebView displaying my site.  As part of the built in 'browser' experience i want a UIActivityIndicator located to let the user know that the site is loading.  Obviously when this is done i want the indicator to disappear.

At the minute, the activity indicator animates, but then keeps animating forever and does not stop or disappear.

The code I am using in .h is as follows;

```
@interface AppSupportWebsite : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@end
```

And within my .m file I have the following; (abbreviated to just show the activity indicator specific code)

```
@synthesize activityIndicator;


- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

I have created an activity indicator within Interface Builder and through Files Owner connected the activityIndicator IBOutlet to the white activity indicator through IB but it just wont disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

select ur activity indicator then

cmd+1

select "hide when stopped"

**check ur webview.delegate=self;**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSLog(@"finished");

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

}
```

Comment: check whether crossed the nslog line.

Comment: I have the indicator selected 'Hide When Stopped' - I have tried every different variation of the options and it makes no difference.

Comment: i got it . u have not connect ur activityindview to ur ivar by IB.i 100% i can sure.please delete that act again add new one then select above action connect it to ur ivar.

Comment: so u have not specify urwebview.delegate=self.

Comment: Through Files Owner I have connected the indicatorview in IB to the activityIndicator IBOutlet i created

Comment: u have not specify urwebview.delegate=self;

Comment: aah thanks Madhu, I just added webView.delegate=self and it worked perfectly.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This is just a stab in the dark, but you may be having issues because the UIWebView Delegate is being called from a different thread other than the main thread.  So you may be getting some race conditions as a result.

Give this Grand Central Dispatch Code (GCD) a try and let me know if that works:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
      [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that code and it made no difference to the bhaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an NSLog statement (just something like NSLog(@"Web Finished Loading!");) to the webViewDidFinishLoad method? My guess is that this method is not being called. There could be a few reasons for that. For instance, if you are releasing the webView before you hit the method, it might not call the method at all.

Comment: Hi, I added NSLog(@"finished"); to the method and there was no feedback in the log

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

It is possible to run above code multiple time it your website have multiple redirects. so I would not suggest to put this line in this delegate method. I would suggest to put this in viewWillAppear delegate method of viewController.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

Also, make sure you bind UIActivityIndicator in your xib.

Hope this help.